# Return value with multiple criteria

Tags: excel

i'm trying to get the following result with a formula. In the picture below you can find 5 possible outcomes from the data.

- Colomn A: check of a test is done
- Colomn B: Testname or testnumber
- Colomn C: Result of the test taken

Every test will get a unique number, but will be duplicated every time a test has been done. Whatever the outcome.

So every test number can only have one `"YES"` in `column A`, all the other attempts should be `"NO"` and if the test results eventually becomes `"SUCCESS"` it should turn `"YES"` in `column A` for this line and all the other attempts should turn to `"NO"` for that particular test number.

The result `"SUCCESS"` overrules everything and `"ERROR"` overrules `"NOT TESTED"`.

I've managed to put `YES` for every unique results, but I'm stuck at turning this `YES` to `NO` if the results is eventually `SUCCESS`.

[image: Outcome examples]

Comment: I'm afraid it is still not clear what exactly you want to reach. Also you put there the picture (which is good!) but unfortunately it is not visible what formulas you have there.

Comment: I dont have any working formulas. The image is just as example so I could explain it a little easier.

Comment: What I'm trying to reach is: daily I get a raw-data file. And I need to report from this file to my manager. 

I cant clean-up this file, has 33k in rows etc. So every testnummer should be counted as 1, even if you can find this in more then 1 row. 

I need to know if a testnummer is SUCCESS, has an ERROR or hasn't been tested before. But evert testnummer can only be counted once.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, it sounds as though you may be able to achieve what you need using the `COUNTIFS` formula, providing you can get a unique list of test names. There is a formula method to get a unique list, but using it on such a large dataset will likely drain your Excel's resource, so it may be easier to just use an advanced filter.

You can use the formula to count per test name the volume of successes, errors and non tests.

I've taken your data from your post as though that were the source data, to give the following output:
[image]

Enter the following formula in `F2`, and you can then drag down and right to fill F-H. You'll obviously need to extend your ranges to suit your actual data source.

> =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$17,$E2,$B$2:$B$17,F$1)

In `I2`, use a simple IF formula to evaluate the counts and return the overall status based on your "Success > Error > Not Tested" heirarchy.

> =IF(F2>0,"Success",IF(G2>0,"Error","Not Tested"))

This should keep it fairly simple to read and alter when required, but if you didn't want the individual status count columns, then you may change the IF formula to include the COUNTIF formulas within, and manually reference the status descriptors, like so:

> =if(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$17,$E2,$B$2:$B$17,"Success")>0,"Success",if(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$17,$E2,$B$2:$B$17,"Error")>0,"Error","Not Tested"))

Comment: Ok this seems to work if start from a fresh data file with only the unique testnumbers.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to dig out the unique numbers from the original data set to perform this. There is a formula to do this but it may be a bit resource intensive given how many rows you're expecting - explained [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/)